# How to call CKEditor 4 plugin function in-page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

Lets say I have CKEditor 4.3 installed (which I do) with the jquery loader. I've loaded a plugin (lets called it 'foobar') which almost does what I want it to. There is a function within the plugin's plugin.js file which I would like to call manually in-page. For this example, lets call the function hello().

I want to call it when a particular link is clicked.

How can I reference the function within the ckeditor plugin?

Here is the plugin.js structure:

```
(function() {
    if (!supportsLocalStorage()) {
        CKEDITOR.plugins.add("foobar", {}); //register a dummy plugin to pass CKEditor plugin initialization process
        return;
    }

    CKEDITOR.plugins.add("foobar", {
        lang: 'de,en,jp,pl,pt-br,sv,zh,zh-cn', // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
        version: 0.10,
        init: function(editor) {
            CKEDITOR.document.appendStyleSheet(CKEDITOR.getUrl(CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath('foobar') + 'css/foobar.min.css'));

            if (typeof (jQuery) === 'undefined') {
                CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', function() {
                    jQuery.noConflict();

                    loadPlugin(editor);
                });

            } else {
                CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(CKEDITOR.getUrl(CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath('foobar') + 'js/extensions.min.js'), function() {
                    loadPlugin(editor);
                });
            }
        }
    });

    function loadPlugin(editorInstance) {
        /*
        load of random stuff that isn't important for this example..
         */
    }



    var hello = function() {
        alert('hello!');
    };
}
```

Comment: function hello won't be in scope to be called outside the IIFE in your example code. If you want to call it, you'd need to add it to the object you're calling CKEDITOR.plugins.add("foobar", [object]) with (or have it globally somewhere else, which is probably not a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the plugin was added something like:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('foobar',
{
    hello: function() { alert('hello'); }
});
```

(e.g., 'hello' is a function on the object passed to CKEDITOR.plugins.add, and not just a function in the file).

`CKEDITOR.plugins.registered.foobar.hello()` should work.

Edit: To call hello in your example, you'd need to attach it to the object you're passing to CKEDITOR.plugins.add. e.g.

```
var hello = function() {
        alert('hello!');
    };

CKEDITOR.plugins.add("foobar", {
        lang: 'de,en,jp,pl,pt-br,sv,zh,zh-cn', // %REMOVE_LINE_CORE%
        version: 0.10,
        init: function(editor) {...},
        hello: hello
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The right definition of the plugin should be as follows:

```
( function() {
    // Definition of the plugin.
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'foo', {
        init: function( editor ) {
            ...
        }
    } );

    // Methods and variables related to the plugin but exposed to the public.
    CKEDITOR.plugins.foo = {
        hello: function() {
            ...
        }
    };
} )();
```

Then simply `CKEDITOR.plugins.foo.hello()`. It's the most common pattern shared among CKEditor core plugins.